# $w.at Event Handler runs recursive when fired on repeater. WIX / Corvid / Velo

Tags: javascript, recursion, event-handling, repeater, velo

I have a pretty simple example of export function (event handler `mouseIn`) which works somehow odd for me.

I have a repeater filled with 150 elements. When I had 10 elements all was fine. But the more elements there are, the slower the function works. Although the problem is different.
[Repeater elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxk7m.jpg)

In the editor the `#repeater` looks like this: there are a `container2` with all elements inside it and the `box1` which is collapsed by default. `box1` contain 3 `dropdowns`. These elements are not connected to any dataset. I mean `container2` `box1` and any of `dropdowns`.
[Repeater in Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DBNu.jpg)

And here are the functions I have on my site:

```
export function container2_mouseIn(event) {
 let $item = $w.at(event.context);
    $item("#box1").expand();
}
export function container2_mouseOut(event) {
 let $item = $w.at(event.context);
    $item("#box1").collapse();
}
export function box1_mouseIn(event) {
 let $item = $w.at(event.context);
    $item("#box1").expand();
}
```

So, as you can see from the functions above I want to achieve with this code is to show `dropdowns` of the related element `#OnMouseIn` and to hide it `#OnMouseOut` of `container2`.

And this works just fine and fast if you have 3-10 items in the repeater. But if you have 20 f.e. you can see that delays of `dropdowns` appearance. When I have 150 items is just working very slow and as I have not only these event handlers I even have an error in Chrome console.

The errors are following:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq1nW.jpg)

What was done next:
I've opened a performance tab in the Chrome and recorded exactly the hover action to look what's going on with it.
And here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/171Cn.jpg)

So mouse out event took 813.6ms. Almost a second. Isn't it weird?
These whole green columns which is beyond the **/ Task =>Event Mouse out=>Function Call /** consists of three repeating

**(anonymous)**
         **_t**
          **r**

Again and again. I don't know what kind of a #recursion is it and why it happens...
[Recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAEu2.jpg)

This happens even when I have 10 elements on the site. Just if I have 150 it can be seen much better. And I'm starting to have an errors Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
I know a little about the stacks but I really don't have an idea from this WIX code what's wrong and why it so?

**Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? And why this kind of recursion happens?**

I was also recording an events related to non-repeater elements. I mean just a separate button on my page. And there is no recursion in this case. Just fast and short function call in the console.

***Thank you in advance. I appreciate any help on this.***

Comment: Repeaters in Wix are heavy and 150 items will surely slow down your page a lot which might be the reason for your issue. Have you considered pagination to show items in batches?

Comment: If you use 150 element per container. The best way is to use custom element to build the repeater using html,js,css and avoid Wix Repeater element.